# Why does changing the operator from '>=' to '>' cause a blank result?

Tags: sql

I'm learning SQL and from a programming point of view I'm struggling to understand why this query is behaving the way it is (from [SQLZOO](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial) Q6)

The question:

"Find the largest country (by area) in each continent, show the continent, the name and the area:"

```
SELECT continent, name, area from world a
WHERE area >= ALL 
(SELECT area from world b WHERE a.continent = b.continent AND area>0)
```

I get the above, fairly simple nested select statement.

However, what I don't get is why changing this line causes a blank result:

`WHERE area >= ALL` - Change it to - `WHERE area > ALL`

Why does this give me a blank result?

**Update:** I'm using **MySQL**

Comment: What is the data you are using? On what platform?

Comment: It can't be `> all` as then it would have to be bigger than itself. Find all countries with an area larger than the area of every country.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By selecting with `>`, you're asking for all countries that are greater than all countries on the same continent. No country can have an area greater than that of all countries on the same continent: even if it is the biggest country on a continent, it is still not bigger than itself.

Comment: I've updated, I made a mistake copying the question over from the tutorial.

Comment: @ben_dchost Ah, okay, then it's just the last part of my answer, I've removed the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's very obvious now you say it - the `country is tested against itself` and fails without `>=`. I think I need a long, long break from my PC :)